# Cannot read property 'autoSend' of null

Tags: android, react-native, sms

I want to send a verification code through sms using the number given by the user but the error "Cannot read property 'autoSend' of null" shows up. Also, I am using `react-native-get-sms-android`

```
const [recipientNumber, setRecipientNumber] = useState('');

  const generateRandomCode = () => {
    return Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
  };

  const randomCode = generateRandomCode().toString();

  const sendRandomCode = async () => {
    var message = "Verification Code: " + randomCode;
    
    SmsAndroid.autoSend(
      recipientNumber, 
      message, 
      'sendDirect', 
      (err, message) => {
        if (err){
          console.log("error");
        } else {
          console.log(message); 
        }
      }
    );
  };
```

what I have tried:

```
const SmsAndroid = require('react-native-sms-android');
```

```
npm i --save-dev @types/react-native-get-sms-android
```

the second one only gave this:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2freact-native-get-sms-android - Not found
npm ERR! 404  '@types/react-native-get-sms-android@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Also tried using `react-native-get-sms-android` but the error is still the same and I tried the same possible solution but they also dont work